# Why am I getting a PDFParseException when attempting to get a page of a PDFFile instance?

Tags: java, pdf, coldfusion, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

I am using [PDFRenderer](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer) version 0.9.1 to convert PDFs to PNG programmatically in ColdFusion.

Here is the UDF I've written to do this:

```xml
<cffunction
    name="pdfToImageFile"
    returntype="String"
    output="false"
    hint="Converts a phsyical PDF File to a physical Image file and returns the absolute path of the new Image file">
    <cfargument name="sourcePath" type="String" default="" />
    <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" default="" />
    <cfargument name="format" type="String" default="png" />

    <cfset var LOCAL = {} />

    <cfif NOT isValidPDF(Trim(ARGUMENTS.sourcePath))>
        <cfthrow
            message="Source file not specified or not a valid PDF file." />
    </cfif>

    <cfif NOT DirectoryExists(Trim(ARGUMENTS.destinationPath))>
        <cfthrow message="Inavlid Destination path." />
    </cfif>

    <cfif
        NOT ListFindNoCase(
                GetWriteableImageFormats(),
                Trim(ARGUMENTS.format)
                )>
        <cfthrow message="Inavlid Image format specified." />
    </cfif>

    <cfscript>
        LOCAL.DestinationFilePath =
                Trim(ARGUMENTS.destinationPath)
            &   "\"
            &   REQUEST.UDFLib.File.getFileNameWithoutExtension(
                    GetFileFromPath(ARGUMENTS.sourcePath)
                    )
            &   "."
            &   LCase(Trim(ARGUMENTS.format));

        LOCAL.RandomAccessFile =
            CreateObject(
                "java",
                "java.io.RandomAccessFile"
                ).init(
                    CreateObject(
                        "java",
                        "java.io.File"
                        ).init(ARGUMENTS.sourcePath),
                    "r"
                    );

        LOCAL.FileChannel = LOCAL.RandomAccessFile.getChannel();

        LOCAL.PDFFile =
            CreateObject(
                "java",
                "com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile"
                ).init(
                    LOCAL.FileChannel.map(
                        CreateObject(
                            "java",
                            "java.nio.channels.FileChannel$MapMode"
                            ).READ_ONLY,
                        0,
                        LOCAL.FileChannel.size()
                        )
                    ) />

        LOCAL.PDFPage = LOCAL.PDFFile.getPage(1) />

        //  The following line throws an exception "Element PDFPAGE is undefined in LOCAL." 
        LOCAL.Rectangle = LOCAL.PDFPage.getBBox();

        LOCAL.BufferedImage =
            CreateObject(
                "java",
                "java.awt.image.BufferedImage"
                ).init(
                    LOCAL.Rectangle.width,
                    LOCAL.Rectangle.height,
                    CreateObject(
                        "java",
                        "java.awt.image.BufferedImage"
                        ).TYPE_INT_RGB
                    );

        LOCAL.Graphics = LOCAL.BufferedImage.createGraphics();

        LOCAL.Graphics.drawImage(
            LOCAL.PDFPage.getImage(
                LOCAL.Rectangle.width,
                LOCAL.Rectangle.height,
                LOCAL.Rectangle,
                JavaCast("null", ""),
                true,
                true
                ),
            0,
            0,
            JavaCast("null", "")
            );

        LOCAL.Graphics.dispose();

        LOCAL.ImageFile =
            CreateObject(
                "java",
                "java.io.File"
                ).init(LOCAL.DestinationFilePath);

        //  Delete existing image file
        if  (LOCAL.ImageFile.exists())
            LOCAL.ImageFile.delete();

        //  Export the image to the specified format
        CreateObject(
            "java",
            "javax.imageio.ImageIO"
            ).write(
                LOCAL.BufferedImage,
                JavaCast("string", Trim(ARGUMENTS.format)),
                LOCAL.ImageFile
                );

        LOCAL.RandomAccessFile.close();

        return LOCAL.DestinationFilePath;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

This works just fine for most PDFs I throw at it. However, it occasionally throws an exception for certain PDFs (all of the PDFs are propietary and cannot be shared).

When attempting to reference the first page of the PDF using `PDFFile.getPage(1)`, I get a ColdFusion exception: `Element PDFPAGE is undefined in LOCAL.`.

I've run this through the debugger, and upon deeper inspection, I see the following values for a certain PDF:

```
PDFFile.getNumPages() : 0
PDFFile.getVersionString() : 1.7
PDFFile.getRoot() : 
    Indirect to #182
    Catalog dictionary. Keys:
       StructTreeRoot  Indirect to #40com.sun.pdfview.PDFParseException: Could not decrypt: Need at least 2880 bytes of space in output buffer
       Pages  Indirect to #178com.sun.pdfview.PDFParseException: Could not decrypt: Need at least 80 bytes of space in output buffer
       Type  Name: /Catalog
       ViewerPreferences  Untyped dictionary. Keys:
       Direction  Name: /L2R
       Metadata  Indirect to #23
    Caught an error: com.sun.pdfview.PDFParseException: Could not decrypt: Need at least 2672 bytes of space in output buffer
       MarkInfo  Untyped dictionary. Keys:
       Marked  Boolean: true
```

I'm not well-versed in Java, so I've no idea what that all means, but it leads me to believe that the PDF is malformed and can't be read properly by the Java library.

Any idea what exactly might cause this type of error? Could it be because of how the PDF is generated/made, being a newer version that is not compatible with the PDFRenderer library?

Comment: FYI, I wrote this UDF based on articles and stackoverflow posts I've read with code examples, so I don't want to take credit for the code (though my version may not be the best anyways).

Comment: FYI, I tried using `CFPDF action="thumbnail"` with one of the same PDFs that threw the above exception, and I also receive an exception with that, so I'm led to believe that the issue is with the PDF.